# Use case for qemu-static for same architecture

Tags: ubuntu, qemu

I just discovered that the 64bit amd version of the Ubuntu package `qemu-user-static` contains the binary `/usr/bin/qemu-x86_64-static`.

Normally, `qemu-user-static` is used for emulating another architecture, so I try to find a reason why they build and deploy an amd64 on amd64 emulator.

The `dd` times show that `qemu-x86_64-static` is more than just a wrapper, but still faster than an armhf emulation on amd64. Maybe there is a use case in debugging, sandboxing and/or security?

native:

```
me:~$ time /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=100000
100000+0 records in
100000+0 records out
51200000 bytes (51 MB) copied, 0.0694854 s, 737 MB/s
real    0m0.075s
user    0m0.017s
sys 0m0.058s
```

emulated:

```
me:~$ time qemu-x86_64-static /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=100000
100000+0 records in
100000+0 records out
51200000 bytes (51 MB) copied, 0.175123 s, 292 MB/s
real    0m0.198s
user    0m0.121s
sys 0m0.076s
```

everything is amd64:

```
me:~$ uname -a
Linux 3.13.0-65-generic #105-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 21 18:50:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

me:~$ file /bin/dd
/bin/dd: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=83e959307f50e08b797447bd3f673b1f0e7c2386, stripped

me:~$ file /usr/bin/qemu-x86_64-static
/usr/bin/qemu-x86_64-static: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=8fb7501ac002a3f2cee4c07c77b9e7232d6c501e, stripped
```

Comment: I betting on "cause the config file was there for other arch." and it's just an automated process, but I would be interested in knowing too.

Answer (score 0):

qemu-x86_64-static also exists in qemu-user-static package which is compiled for ARM architecture. It is so useful if you need to run x86 compiled applications on ARM environment. I think same codebase for qemu is compiled for all architectures without filtering. That's why it comes on X86 qemu-user-static package also. As a side note, qemu-user-static package at ARM also contains qemu-arm-static ;)

Comment: qemu-x86_64-static has a clear use case in arm package, this is not an answer. the remaining part is less helpful than @coteyr's comment